# jQuery - Hide & Show Specific iFrames on a Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a site with several embedded YouTube videos using iframes. I hide all of them to start, they're being covered up by a thumbnail image. They need to show when the thumbnail image is clicked.

I had a working solution, but it required me adding classes or ids to each iframe/thumbnail. I will not be able to add any classes or ids to the iframe or the thumbnail image.

Here is what I had:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
<!-- Hide iFrames -->
$(".contentIframe1").hide();
$(".contentIframe2").hide();
    <!-- iFrame1 Click Function -->
    $(".play-thumbnail1").click(function(){
        $(".contentIframe1").show();
    });
    <!-- iFrame2 Click Function -->
    $(".play-thumbnail2").click(function(){
        $(".contentIframe2").show();
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<iframe class="contentIframe1" width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embedurl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  <div class="play-button"></div>
  <img class="play-thumbnail1" src="imgurl" alt="" />
```

Would it be possible to get the same effect without adding different classes to each thumbnail and iframe?

Here's the new html for every single iframe on the page:

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embedurl></iframe>

  <div class="play-button"></div>
  <img class="play-thumbnail" src="imgurl" alt="" />
```

Here's the new jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
<!-- Hide iFrames -->
$("iframe").hide();
    <!-- iFrame Click Function -->
$(".play-thumbnail").click(function(){
$("iframe").show();
});     
});
```

This of course just hides and shows them all at the same time. I figured I'd have to use .each() to loop through each of the thumbnails and somehow make it only show the corresponding iFrame.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)** to get the corresponding `iframe`

```
$(".play-thumbnail").click(function(){
    //if you need to hide currenly visible iframes use $('iframe').hide()
    $(this).closest('div').children("iframe").show();
});
```

Comment: I tried adding this, but nothing happens when I click on the thumbnail. So, you're saying it's impossible without classes being added?

Comment: It is possible. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/2zyxzgsa/1/. Where are you adding your click event and how is the html structure where the code doesn't work?

Comment: I'm currently just adding the click event in a <script> tag right before the end of my <head> section. The html looks exactly like the fiddle, strange. According to your note this won't solve my problem anyway though, I have multiple iframes and I can't add classes.

Comment: The first two images in the grid are using the .play-thumbnail class and have iframes. There's currently only two on the page, but there will be more.

Comment: Check the updated code or just replace `$(this).closest('div').children("iframe").show();`. This works for your site.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. Currently, the videos are set to autoplay. I need them to start playing when the thumbnail is clicked. I tried adding: videoURL += "&autoplay=1";
    $(this).closest('div').find("iframe").prop('src',videoURL); but this breaks the video.

Comment: Lifesaver. Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add `class` to them -

```
<iframe class='myclass' ...
```

And Try this -

```
$('.myclass').each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
})
```

If you need to add some checks then -

```
$('.myclass').each(function() {
  if (check) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
})
```